# Can I make a public folder (accessible for user) on internal storage

Tags: android, directory, backup

I want to take backup from my android app db. Backup file must be accessible for the user and not removed when the user uninstalls app.
 I want to know can I have a directory with appropriate properties (mentioned above) in internal storage to save my backups there?

Thanks in advance